# Upgrade a package

Tags: linux, packages, rdiff-backup

I have an Ubuntu 8.04 server and I wanted to install rdiff-backup
I have done:

```
apt-get install rdiff-backup
```

But when I launched it return me a lot of error.
i have seen in internet that the problem is the old version of rdiff-backup
I have check the version and is: 1.1.15-1

i need the new version of the package how can I retrieve?
I have tried:
`apt-get update rdiff-backup`

but nothing

`apt-get update`

but nothing

Comment: What version of ubuntu? ...desktop or server version? And "apt-get update" (as root of course) should update your repository information... does that generate output to indicate it can see the repositories when it runs?

Comment: It's a server version and I have run the update but no rdiff-backup was updated

Comment: exactly what version of ubuntu? Once you know your version ("lsb_release -a" I think should show you)

Comment: Mi version of Ubuntu is 8.04  @craig

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/ is awesome for resolving these sorts of questions. I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8.04LTS is no longer supported; so they are no longer releasing package updates for it. The Ubuntu packages web site shows you have the [current rdiff-backup](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rdiff-backup&searchon=names&suite=hardy&section=all) installed.

You will need to install the version you want by hand, or you will need to upgrade your entire Ubuntu system to 10.04. If you upgrade to 10.04LTS, (which is end of life in April 2015,) then you'd be able to "apt-get" update your [rdiff-backup to 1.2.8](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rdiff-backup&searchon=names&suite=lucid&section=all)

Comment: I can't update is a server with many sites with many procedure and is managed by an agency. I can only enter by ssh but I don't know if is possible to upgrade all system

Comment: ...then you will need to consider installing rdiff-backup by hand. You might be able to find a pre-built package for it (no idea where, sorry.) I'd guess you'll need to d/l the source and compile it. But you're beyond your original question now -- you cannot upgrade this package via apt-get when you are in 8.04.

Answer (score 1):

By running

```
apt-cache show rdiff-backup | grep Version
```

you can see the versions of rdiff-backup that are available to you in your package manager.  By default,

```
apt-get install
```

will install the newest version of a package, which means the version of rdiff-backup that you have installed is the newest available in your package repository.

This leaves you with two options:

1. Compile and install rdiff-backup from source
2. Find a newer version of rdiff-backup package for your operating system.

For example, http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rdiff-backup shows that newer versions of rdiff-backup are available in lucid, oneiric, precise, quantal and raring.

Comment: I have done with apt-get install but hasn't install the last version

Comment: I can install only with terminal because is a server and I connect to it by ssh